# If T(S) is linearly independent, show S is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $T: V \to W$ be a linear transformation. Let $S = \{v_1,...,v_k\}$ and assume $T(S)$ is linearly independent. Show S is also linearly independent.

I think I just have to prove that if $a_1 v_1 + ... + a_k v_k = 0$ then all $a_i$ must be 0 but am not sure how and how to use the fact that T(S) is linearly independent.

Would this be a valid proof?

$a_1 v_1 + ... + a_k v_k = 0$

$T(a_1v_1 + ... a_k v_k) = 0$
but T(S) is linearly independent so all $a_i$ must be 0
so $a_1 v_1 + ... + a_k v_k$ is linearly independent

Thank you.

Comment: Your proof hasn't made explicit use of the assumption that $T$ is linear. So it needs some work. In order to prove this, you should also consider the contrapositive of this implication.

Comment: In your last two lines, how precisely do you use the linear independence of $T(S)$ to conclude that all $a_i$ must be $0$? Also, you need to use some words to separate statements. a_1v_1 + ... + a_k v_k = 0 T(a_1v_1 + ... a_k v_k) = 0 is pretty meaningless, for example. Perhaps you mean "If $a_1v_1 + \dots + a_k v_k = 0$, then $T(a_1v_1 + \dots+ a_k v_k) = 0$"?

Answer (score 3):

Your proof as it is written now is not valid, since $T(a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_k v_k)=0$ doesn't imply that all $a_i=0$. However, since $T$ is linear you have
$$
T(a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_k v_k) = 
a_1 T(v_1) + \cdots + a_k T(v_k)
$$
where you now have a linear combination of the elements of $T(S)$.

Comment: Ok so how about this: Let a_1 v_1 + ... a_k v_k = 0, then the transformation of S is T(S) = T(a_1 v_1 + ... + a_k v_k) = 0, and T is linear so a_1 T(v_1) + ... + a_k T(v_k) = 0, but T(S) is linearly independent so all a_i must be 0. Is this ok?

Comment: @mch No, it's not okay. The set $T(S)$ of vectors in $W$ can not be equal to the single vector $T(a_1 v_1+\cdots+a_k v_k)$ in $W$, so $T(S)=T(a_1 v_1+\cdots+a_k v_k)$ is equally wrong as $\mathbb R=4$.

Comment: Can you tell me how to go about this please?

Answer (score 2):

Yes your proof is almost correct and it's a **direct** proof and to complete it we write:
$$0=T(a_1v_1 + \cdots a_k v_k)=a_1T(v_1)+\cdots+a_kT(v_k)$$
so the $a_i$ are $0$ since $T(S)$ is linearly dependent.

There's also a proof by **contradiction**:

assume that $S$ isn't linearly independent and WLOG we more assume that
$$v_1=\sum_{p=2}^k\alpha_p v_p$$
hence we apply $T$ and we have
$$T(v_1)=\sum_{p=2}^k\alpha_pT(v_p)$$
which means that $T(S)$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: His proof is incorrect, and he even calls $\;a_1v_1+\ldots+a_kv_k\;$ "lin. ind.", which seems to indicate a basic lack of understanding.

Comment: The OP's proof is *almost* correct, but yes  probably he didn't know how to complete it.

Comment: Well @Sami, I don't think he's that close as he didn't even use the lin. ind. of $\;\{Tv_1,..,Tv_k\}\;$ ...

Comment: Well @DonAntonio , by confronting everyday  the mistakes of my students that are far more blatant I think I got a little flexible in my assessment of this kind of answer:-)

Comment: I've deleted the last few comments in this thread. Keep it polite, people.