# Suppose $S$ is linearly independent set of vectors, $T\subseteq S$, then $T$ is linearly independent (alternate method)

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, alternative-proof

I know this question has answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756520/if-ts-is-linearly-independent-show-s-is-linearly-independent) but they involve linear transformations which I haven't reached upto yet. There was a proof by contradiction there as well but I had a different idea in mind:

Let $S=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ where $v$ is a vector. Assume that $T$ is linearly dependent. So there exists scalars $t_1,t_2,...,t_m$, not all zero such that the relation of linear dependence on $T$ becomes
$$t_1v_1+t_2v_2+...+t_mv_m=0 \tag{1}$$
where $m<n$ (i.e. choose any number and combination of vectors from $S$ but not all vectors from $S$). Now add $0\times\sum v_i$, where $v_i$ denotes those vectors from $S$ not chosen in $(1)$, to $(1).$ Hence,
$$t_1v_1+t_2v_2+...+t_mv_m+0\sum v_i=0 \tag{2}$$
But this is the relation of linear dependence on $S$ which suggests that there exists scalars not all zero such that $(2)$ holds true. This contradicts our assumption that $S$ was linearly independent. Hence $T$ is linearly independent. $\Box$

I am self-teaching Linear Algebra and theres no solution for this problem in my book, so I'm looking to see if my english/correctness of this proof flows smoothly.

> Is this proof of contradiction done correctly? Any flaws or is it fine?

Comment: The question you reference has nothing to do with the question you pose. Your proof is the standard one (provided the sets in question are finite).

Comment: Actually no proof is needed. By definition a set of vectors $S$ is linearly independent if any finite nonzero linear combination  of vectors from $S$ is a nonzero vector. In particular this holds for any subset $T$ of $S.$